# Issue with clicking Share APP link in Action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I added Share App and Rate us links to Action bar.It shows nicely.
When click on Rate us ,it will open Play store link.It's OK.
But when click on Share App,it will open sharing dialog and App store link also.
I want to disable opening App store link when click Share App.
Another problem,
    When click back button in app store page,it will go to Play store.But I want to go back to my app.
    How to solve my 2 issues...?please help me

Here is my Java code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_share:

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String.format(getString(R.string.txt_share_me), "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName()));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));

            case R.id.id_rateus:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=PackageName")));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my Menu code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/id_rateus"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_rateus"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `break;` after your share case and
Use

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
```

To access your app via the play store

Comment: *break: code working.
*I added second code.but when click app store back button not coming to my app.only physical back button works.

Comment: I do not think you can change the default behavior of the play store, you will have to use the 'physical' back button to close the window.